# RegExp String replace Error

Tags: javascript

i want to replace all occurrences of "+" in a string with a space

```
    Query = Query.replace(new RegExp("+", "g")," ");
```

But it raises error "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier" on above line
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: In the answers below they are escaping the + character because it has special meaning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Query.replace(/\+/g, "");
```

You will need to backslash the `+`

Answer (score 1):

> Query.replace(/+/g,' ');

Will replace any occurrences of + with space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Query = Query .replace(new RegExp("\\+", "g")," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
    `Query = Query.replace(/\+/g, " ");`